# W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection error

Tags: android

I am getting a W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection error when I try to login to app.
Had a look at other answers but none solve my issue.I can register a user but I cant login to the app.

Heres the code that connects to the DB for registration and login.From my limited knowledge of this my connections are closed .

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private String reg_url = "http://xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx/register.php";
private String login_url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxxx/login.php";
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


public BackgroundTask(Context context)
{

    this.context = context;
    activity = (Activity) context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to Server...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{

    String method = params[0];

    if (method.equals("register"))
    {

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            String name = params[1];
            String email = params[2];
            String password = params[3];
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {

                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");

            }


            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else if (method.equals("login"))
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));


            String email,password;

            email = params[1];
            password = params [2];
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("userame", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {

                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");

            }


            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String json)
{
   try
   {

       progressDialog.dismiss();


       Log.v("JSON", json);
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
       JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
       JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
       String code = JO.getString("code");
       String message = JO.getString("message");



       if(code.equals("reg_true"))
       {
           showDialog("Sucessful registration.Thank you.Enjoy_AS!", message, code);
       }

       else if (code.equals("reg_false"))
       {
           showDialog("User Already exists_AS", message, code);
       }

       else if (code.equals("login_true"))
       {

           Intent intent = new Intent(activity, News.class);
           intent.putExtra("message", message);
           activity.startActivity(intent);

       }
       else if (code.equals("login_false"))
       {
           showDialog("Login Error_AS", message, code);
       }


   } catch (JSONException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }


}

public void  showDialog(String title,String message,String code)
{

    builder.setTitle(title);
    if (code.equals("reg_true") || code.equals("reg_false"))
    {
        builder.setMessage(message);//message from server
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                activity.finish();

            }
        });


    }

    else if (code.equals("login_false"))
    {


        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                EditText email,password;



                email = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.email);
                password = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.password);

                email.setText("");
                password.setText("");
                dialog.dismiss();


            }


        });


    }
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

This is the login

```
Button login_button;
EditText email, password;
TextView signup_text;
AlertDialog.Builder alert;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    signup_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
    signup_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Register.class));

        }
    });



    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (email.getText().toString().equals("") || password.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                alert.setTitle("Login Failed");
                alert.setMessage("Try again");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            } else  //if user provides proper data
            {
                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(Login.this);
                backgroundTask.execute("login", email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
            }

        }


    });


}


}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but I'm running a basic master/detail program on Android Studio 2.0 with a Genymotion emulator.  And I haven't changed a line of code yet!